# Why is a overencompassing try: / except: not enough to catch an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I though that an outermost `try:` / `except:` would always catch an exception (the fact that this is probably not a good idea is outside of the question):

```
try:
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except:
        raise ValueError
except:
    pass
```

In [some code](https://github.com/jamesoff/simplemonitor/blob/75950ea4ff8a1a809da4a0c26b068afc0f9eea5f/Loggers/network.py#L81) I am going though, I faced the case where

```
def process_batch(self):
    try:
        p = util.json_dumps(self.batch_data)
        mac = hmac.new(self.key, p)
        send_bytes = struct.pack('B', mac.digest_size) + mac.digest() + p
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            try:
                s.connect((self.host, self.port))
            except socket.error:
                s.close()
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect((self.host, self.port))
            s.send(send_bytes)
        finally:
            s.close()
    except Exception:
        self.logger_logger.exception("Failed to send network data")
```

raised an exception:

```
2019-02-09 23:32:51     INFO (simplemonitor) monitor passed: hass
2019-02-09 23:32:51     INFO (simplemonitor) monitor passed: dns
2019-02-09 23:32:51    ERROR (simplemonitor.logger-send-to-srv) Failed to send network data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/simplemonitor/Loggers/network.py", line 89, in process_batch
    s.connect((self.host, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/simplemonitor/Loggers/network.py", line 93, in process_batch
    s.connect((self.host, self.port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Why is it so? Why hasn't the overencompassing `try:`/`except:` caught the exception?

Comment: Because another exception is being raised by the inner exception handling code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Any chance you can post a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you sure the `Traceback` isn't printed by [`logger.exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception)?

Comment: @martineau: but wouldn't that another exception be handled by the first (widest) `try`?

Comment: @metatoaster: ah. I am not sure that I understand what you mean but I  had a look a few lines up (and added them to the question, above the Traceback)  and realized that the message from the outermost `except` **is printed** ("Failed to send network data"). So now i do not indeed understand where the Traceback comes from.

Comment: With regards to the update, replace `self.logger_logger.exception` with `self.logger_logger.error`, and the logger will not include the Traceback in the stream, if you don't want the `Traceback` to be included as part of the log message.

Comment: @metatoaster: ahhhh, I get it now. `self.logger_logger.exception`will include the Traceback. Thanks a lot. If you would not mind to turn that into an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the provided second code example, the `Traceback` message was not in fact an unhandled exception, due to the exception handler calling [`logger.exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) method which will print out the specified message along with the complete `Traceback` message into the logging stream.  If the `Traceback` is not desired, using `logger.error` will produce the log message at the same `ERROR` level without it.